# Displaying AVPlayer in QML

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, qml, avplayer

I'm working on a DRM feature for playing video in my QML application on IOS devices. I managed to play the "video" (sound only) using IOS native player (`AVPlayer`), and currently struggling on getting the video inside the application. Prior to that I worked only with pure QML code.

Since I'm not that experienced with the combination of objective-c and QT/QML, is it possible to display `AVPlayer` inside QML?

Or can I use QTs mediaplayer to achieve the same as this:

```
ViewRightKeyLoaderDelegate *loaderDelegate;

AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movieURL options:nil];
loaderDelegate = [[ViewRightKeyLoaderDelegate alloc] init];
[[asset resourceLoader] setDelegate:loaderDelegate queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

playerItem = [[[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset] autorelease] ;
player = [[[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem] autorelease];

AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerViewController.player = player;
[player play];
```

The delegate is based on `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` if needed I'll put the implementation.

I came across QTAv and currently checking if I can do the above with it.

Comment: I have no knowledge about avplayer, but as long as there is a Qt media player plugin using it, it should be possible. Otherwise you could (theoretically) create such a plugin... (but thats not a trivial task)

Comment: I ended up making a custom qtmultimedia build with the added modifications.